# Changing the RGB for longname/shortname to default colors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When using plot() in Matlab the default colors differ from what the docs call
the longnames/shortnames, which can be supplied in lieu of RGB triples. 
For example:

```
n = 10;
a = rand(n,1);
b = rand(n,1);
w = 1e-1;
p = 1:n;

plot(p,a,p,b,p,a+w,'b',p,b+w,'r','LineWidth',3);
```

I'd like to know if there was a way to setting these longnames/shortnames
to the default (2015b) colors.

**EDIT**

@Geoff provided the easiest way to do what I asked originally. Let me try to sharpen up my question. I was hoping to keep the default color order but assign the new default blue (rgb = [0 0.4470 0.7410]) to the 'b' shortname. I know this may seem sort of fussy but I prefer the new default blue to the "canonical" blue (rgb = [0 0 1]).

Answer (score 1):

The default "blue" and "red" you are seeing come from the colormap [lines](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#buc3wsn-8), which by default are the colors used by `plot` . You can edit the default plotting colormap like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/defining-the-color-of-lines-for-plotting.html).

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer as far as I know, but please include all relevant parts of the code in the answer as well, for completeness.